# How can I make a Stata plugin not depend on the order of variables?

Tags: c++, c, stata

I am writing a plugin for Stata in C++, and it seems to me that accessing the data depends on the order of variables passed to the plugin, as `SF_vdata()` only takes integer arguments to index the variables.

The best solution I have at the moment, is to first run `ds`, store the macro containing all variable names, and then call my plugin. My plugin can then search the macro for the variable that it is interested in, and get the index base don its position in the list.

This works, but I would like my plugin not to depend on certain Stata commands being run first. I know this is silly, as the plugin requires the dataset to be formatted in a specific way, but something feels wrong about first having to call `ds` and store a macro before calling my plugin.

Is there anyway to access the order of variable names from inside the plugin if `ds` is not called first?

Comment: Plugins were supported by StataCorp largely because some people were vocal that they wanted or needed them, but the public uptake was very small. (There may well have been exceptions inside large firms or institutions developing code purely for internal use.) Either way -- and I know this is unlikely to be the answer you seek -- my guess is that you would find it much, much easier to use Mata for what you want. The support for plugins is essentially minimal, as you have discovered, a largely chicken-and-egg matter as so few user-programmers ever wrote any or showed interest in writing any.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nick. Unfortunately your macro solution is the only answer, and is what I use. You can only access the data directly using the SF_data functions, as a "matrix", and that's all you get by default, there are no headers like in a table. I use macros to save all the data information and pass the whole dataset, reading the variable I'm interested in, just like you, and even wrote translators to retain the format settings, but have not yet used the value labels.